# "&" or ",": What is the difference between A<T extends I1 & I2> and A<T extends I1 , I2>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, separator

**Multiple generic interface separator: "," or "&"**

I was always using `A<T extends I1, I2>` but today, I saw `A<T extends I1 & I2>`.
What is the difference between these two notation?

Does it have a different meaning? Purpose?

Comment: good catch of the inconsistency

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
A<T extends I1, I2>
```

is a type `A` with two parameters

1. `T` which must be a subtype of `I1`
2. `I2`

You can read this as "A <preposition> type T which extends I1 <preposition> type I2",
so `SortedMap<Key extends comparable, Value>` is a "map from comparable type key to type value"

---

```
A<T extends I1 & I2>
```

is a type `A` with a single parameter

1. `T` which must be a subtype of `I1` and a subtype of `I2`

You can read this as "A <preposition> type T which extends I1 and I2" so a `SortedSerializableSet<T extends Serializable & Comparable>` can be read "a sorted set of elements of type T which is both serializable and comparable"

Comment: You are right! I had been disturbed by the `extends` which made me think that I1 and I2 were associated to T... Shame on me...

Comment: Note also that the coma (`,`) is used when a class implements multiple interfaces but `&` is not allowed there... This is confusing...

Comment: @NicolasCenerario, I agree that `,` is confusing.  Ideally in type signatures they would have reused `implements` or used punctuation like (`|`) that conveys the idea that you are expanding the set of left-hand-sides which can  accept values of the type being declared.

Comment: Maybe it's just your wording, but the SortedSerializableSet won't be serializable or comparable. The type T, however, will be.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I intended for the subordinate clause "which ..." to modify "type T" not "set".  I made up `SortedSerializableSet` and in my mind it is serializable but not comparable but there's no reason why it couldn't be comparable.